# Concurrency in monitor while having two function calls coming from the same, other object

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a monitor object in Java which is basically built like this, while skipping irrelevant code:

```
public class TasksQueue {
    private final Lock tasksLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition newTask = tasksLock.newCondition();
    private final List<Task> taskList = new LinkedList<>();

    public Task getNextTask(BufferState buffer){
        tasksLock.lock();
        //if conditions not met await    
        (!placeholder_check()){
            try {
                newTask.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        newTask = taskList.remove(0);
        return newTask;
    }  

    public void addNextTask(Task task){
        tasksLock.lock();
        taskList.add(task);
        newAnyTask.signal();
        tasksLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Currently two other classes have access to this object, one of which only takes items out of the queue, another only adds items to it and signals the first one in the process as seen in the code.

My question is - can I move both enqueuing end dequeuing operations to be taken care of by one class (the second object enqueuing through the first one), and will it cause a deadlock as the object will "hang" on the await and stop letting others enqueue items which will completely halt the queue, or will the two method calls be seen as "separate" objects waiting in the monitor for Java?

The code for checking the types of added tasks and reacting accordingly was omitted here since it's not the core of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you are confusing core concepts related to multithreaded programming.

It's not the object that gets blocked on a monitor, it's the thread that gets blocked.

You can put entire code that uses this queue into single class and create a single object. That won't cause any issue.

However, to execute this code you'd use multiple threads. The thread that executes the code that tries to read from queue will be blocked (if queue is empty), however it won't stop the other thread from executing the code that will add element to the queue and signal, to resume operation of blocked threads.

I highly recommend a book Java Concurrency In Practice.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, if I merge adding and taking out from the queue in a single object (that extends Thread) interacting with the monitor I will block it from functioning since I will block the whole Thread and therefore stop the whole queue? Or does Java treat it as two threads underneath, delegating every method call that tries to acquire the lock as separate entities?

Comment: One thread is one thread. Java won't automatically duplicate it or anything. BTW: You should not extend Threads, it's a bad practice. Implement class with business logic as a separate class. You should be passing Runnable to thread upon creation. (even better solution would be to use ThreadPool, but I'm guessing you're only experimenting right now).